# Django collectstatic on S3 uploads unchanged files everytime on Heroku

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have set up Django with boto and S3, and disabled the automatic COLLECTSTATIC setting on Heroku. The following is my settings.py file.

```
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'BLEHBLEHBLEH'
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'BLEHBLEHBLEH'
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'website-static'
    AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
    AWS_LOCATION = "static_media"
    MEDIA_URL = 'https://website-static.s3.amazonaws.com/static_media/'
    STATIC_URL = 'https://website-static.s3.amazonaws.com/static_media/'
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'https://website-static.s3.amazonaws.com/static_media/admin/'
```

I have done a bit of research, and also installed dateutils==1.2 in my `requirements.txt`, but `python manage.py collectstatic` continues to upload every file regardless of whether or not they are changed. Any ideas?

Comment: What about `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT`?

Comment: did you find the cause and fix?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) of the `collectstatic` command, when the command is executed files are copied over to the location declared by `STATIC_ROOT`.

> Collects the static files into STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` is primarily used by the built in `StaticFilesStorage` and is ignored by the `django-storages` classes